# What is the use of AmbientValue Attribute?

Tags: c#, properties, attributes

I came across this class `AmbientValueAttribute`.
Its an attribute you can specify on a property of a class.
I read the whole page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ambientvalueattribute.aspx including the example. But its usage is still unclear to me.

It seems to me its merely an indication that the property is reflecting a property of another object (why ever do that?). Or is there more to it?

So whats the use of this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really late, but I know the answer.

When you drop a Button on the designer surface, its Font is always the same as its container's Font. This makes sense: if you set the Form's Font to something special, you probably want all your controls to have a special font too.

That's how "ambient" properties work. While the property might have a default, the attribute suggests the designer should use a parent's value instead. If no parent has a value for the property, the "real" default will be used.

I don't know if it actually works, I can't say I've ever tried the attribute myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used this attribute myself, but I *think* is is used to give visual designer tools an indication of what should be the default value of a property.

The code example is of a color property where I think the ambient value is the value shown if no value is set for the property. So in the example, if you have a designer for the AlertForeColor property, the value "Empty" will be shown if no value is selected.

I think the idea is that you can give the user a better experience by displaying the Ambient value instead of the actual value which could be a blank for instance.

Now, I haven't used this attribute myself, but I think this is the intended use of it.

Comment: Sounds logical. But then I would expect the framework to use it iself in TextBox class for example (source: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/MIT/System/Web/UI/MobileControls/TextBox@cs/1305376/TextBox@cs) but I cant find it there, neither in the `System.Windows.Forms.Button` class.

Comment: Yeah. I did a search on Google code search and Ohloh and neither returned any interesting results, but a search on GitHub returns some usages. It seems to be used as a way to give a default value without setting the property value itself.

Comment: I got that `give a default value without setting the property value itself.` as well. But thats the exact purpose of `DefaultValueAttribute`.